# first questions and answers is repeating when i set into the textview?

Tags: java, android, json

I have a lot of questions and answers in my mysql database , i am creating quiz app  when I set them up, i am getting all questions and answer through mysql database using json then the first question  and answers I get it. How can I set the all Questions and answers how can i am using loop in my code please help?

```
    json_string=getIntent().getExtras().getString("j");
    try {
        jsonObject=new JSONObject(json_string);
        jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        if(jsonArray.length()!=0){
            JSONObject JO=jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            Ques = JO.getString("QuestionText");
            Options=JO.getString("Options").split("##");
            ans = Integer.parseInt(JO.getString("CorrectAnswer"));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {

        } else {

            Answers=extras.getString("urAnswers");
        }
    }
    l=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Review);
    ScrollView scrollView= new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout Lin =new LinearLayout(this);
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        TextView Qus = new TextView(this);
        Qus.setTextSize(20);
        Qus.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        Qus.setPadding(0, 20, 0, 0);
        Qus.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        TextView OptA = new TextView(this);
        TextView OptB = new TextView(this);
        TextView OptC = new TextView(this);
        TextView OptD = new TextView(this);
        TextView urans = new TextView(this);
        TextView correctans = new TextView(this);
        Qus.setText (" Question. No.(" + (QuestionNo + 1) + ").\n " + Ques);
        OptA.setText("(a). " + Options[0].toString() + "\n");
        OptB.setText("(b). " + Options[1].toString() + "\n");
        OptC.setText("(c). " + Options[2].toString() + "\n");
        OptD.setText("(d). " + Options[3].toString() + "\n\n");

        String a = "";
        int color = 0;
        String Answers1 = Answers.substring(i, i + 1);
        String correct = String.valueOf(ans);
        if (Answers1.equals("5")) {
            a = "UnAnswered";
            color = Color.YELLOW;
        }
        if (Answers1.equals("1")) {
            a = "A";
            if (correct.equals("1"))
                color = Color.GREEN;
            else
                color = Color.RED;
        }
        if (Answers1.equals("2")) {
            a = "B";
            if (correct.equals("2"))
                color = Color.GREEN;
            else
                color = Color.RED;
        }
        if (Answers1.equals("3")) {
            a = "C";
            if (correct.equals("3"))
                color = Color.GREEN;
            else
                color = Color.RED;
        }
        if (Answers1.equals("4")) {
            a = "D";
            if (correct.equals("4"))
                color = Color.GREEN;
            else
                color = Color.RED;
        } else {
        }

        String b = "";


        if (correct.equals("1")) {
            b = "A";
        }
        if (correct.equals("2")) {
            b = "B";
        }
        if (correct.equals("3")) {
            b = "C";
        }
        if (correct.equals("4")) {
            b = "D";
        } else {

        }

        urans.setText("Your Answer :" + a.toString() + "\n");
        urans.setTextSize(18);
        urans.setTextColor(color);
        correctans.setText("Correct Answer :" + b.toString() + "\n\n");
        correctans.setTextSize(18);
        correctans.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        Lin.addView(Qus);
        Lin.addView(OptA);
        Lin.addView(OptB);
        Lin.addView(OptC);
        Lin.addView(OptD);
        Lin.addView(urans);
        Lin.addView(correctans);
        OptA.setTextSize(18);
        //OptA.setPadding(0,30,0,0);
        OptA.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                .WRAP_CONTENT));
        OptA.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        OptB.setTextSize(18);
        OptB.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        //OptA.setPadding(0,30,0,0);
        OptB.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                .WRAP_CONTENT));
        OptC.setTextSize(18);
        OptA.setPadding(0, 30, 0, 0);
        OptC.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                .WRAP_CONTENT));
        OptC.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        OptD.setTextSize(18);
        //OptA.setPadding(0,30,0,0);
        OptD.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                .WRAP_CONTENT));
        OptD.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    scrollView.addView(Lin);
    scrollView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    scrollView.setPadding(20,10,10,20);
    Lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.back3);
    setContentView(scrollView);
}

}
```

Comment: You are using scrollView and creating layout at runtime. I think its better to serialize your json and use RecyclerView instead.

Comment: how to use please help me

Comment: Refer this :: http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

First of learn to how to use `RecyclerView` here is the link [RecyclerView tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) and learn how to parse json [json parsing tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) Learning these 2 tutorial will sure help you for this problem as well as in future.